# jQuery - Resizable Aspect Ratio Just For One Handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resize, jquery-ui-resizable

I just want to protect aspect ratio from one handle. I tried to run it with this code but it doesn't helped me. Do you have any solutions?

```
  $( "#resizable").resizable({
   handles: 'se,e,w',
   aspectRatio: true,
    start: function(e,ui) {
      if (jQuery(e.originalTarget).hasClass("ui-resizable-se")) {
         aspectRatio: false;
      }
    }
      });
```

Special thanks to any solution..

EDIT: Problem SOLVED. You can see solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18101710/2572291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many unanswered questions about this bug.

Here is the solution that works for you :)

http://jsfiddle.net/882k9/

```
    <script>
    var changedRatio  = "DK"; //DK->dont keep
    var nowResizing   = "NO";
    $(function() {
      $('#resizable').resizable({
          start:function(event,ui){
            nowResizing = "YES";
          },
          stop:function(event,ui){
            nowResizing = "NO";
          }
        });
      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-resizable-e', function(){
          if(changedRatio!="DK"){
            if(nowResizing!="YES"){
              var targetDiv = $(this).parent().attr("id");
              dontKeep(targetDiv);
            }
          }
      });

      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-resizable-se', function(){
          if(changedRatio!="K"){
            if(nowResizing!="YES"){
              var targetDiv = $(this).parent().attr("id");
              keep(targetDiv);
            }
          }
      });
      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-resizable-s', function(){
          if(changedRatio!="DK"){
            if(nowResizing!="YES"){
              var targetDiv = $(this).parent().attr("id");
              dontKeep(targetDiv);
            }
          }
      });
    });

function dontKeep(val){
    $("#"+val).resizable("destroy");
    $("#"+val).resizable({
      aspectRatio:false,
      start:function(event,ui){
          nowResizing = "YES";
        },
      stop:function(event,ui){
          nowResizing = "NO";
      }
    });
    changedRatio  = "DK";
  }
  function keep(val){
    $("#"+val).resizable("destroy");
    $("#"+val).resizable({
      aspectRatio:true,
      start:function(event,ui){
          nowResizing = "YES";
        },
      stop:function(event,ui){
          nowResizing = "NO";
      }
    });
    changedRatio  = "K";
  }
    </script>


<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation that worked for me, perhaps because of newer version of jQuery. The handles at the four corners will maintain the aspect ratio, while the handles on the sides won't.

```
$elements.resizable({
  handles: "all",

  start: function(event, ui) {
    var handle = $(this).data('ui-resizable').axis;

    // We should maintain the aspect ratio for corners, not for sides
    var maintain_aspect_ratio = (["n", "e", "s", "w"].indexOf(handle) == -1);

    $(this).resizable( "option", "aspectRatio", maintain_aspect_ratio )
      .data('ui-resizable')
      ._aspectRatio = maintain_aspect_ratio;
  }, 

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that worked for me

```
var is_se = ($(this).data('uiResizable').axis == "se");
$(this).resizable( "option", "aspectRatio", is_se ).data('uiResizable')._aspectRatio = is_se;
```

Comment: This gives me error... saying can not use option method while resizing...

Comment: try using it on the start event. I'll get back to my code ASAP and tell you how I made it work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide an aspect ratio rather than `true`.

```
aspectRatio: 16 / 9
```

OR

```
aspectRatio: 4 / 3
```

Refer http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#aspect-ratio

OR

```
$( "#resizable:not(ui-resizable-se)").resizable({
   handles: 'se,e,w',
   aspectRatio: 16/9
});
```

Comment: No, there are two options for aspectRatio, you can use numbers or boolean values.

Comment: Yes infact you could. There are many bugs still open in their tracking system regarding changing aspect ratios after initializing. Try something creative to set the aspect ratio on initialization or if you want to change it on the fly you could destroy and initialize it again.

Comment: I couldn't create something that run for me this is why I asked others help to me..

Comment: @Adam: I can re-edit my answer for a simpler solution. We are here to guide you and clear your questions and provide sample pieces of code, not code the whole scenario for free. If you want someone to code for you, you could visit elance.com .

Comment: In any case, I don't want anyone to code whole scenario for me. I just want to see more clear answers that will help me solving my problem.

Comment: I'm very close to solve this problem, I've found some creative solution. Please check this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027887/jquery-resizable-live

Comment: maybe you need in the future, he solved : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18101710/2572291