# jQuery resizable .Live()

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, resizable

When I try to destroy resizable div, hover function on .ui-resizable-se doesn't work. I think I have to use jquery live(). But I couldn't integrate it clearly.

If you hover .ui-resizable-se or .ui-resizable-e when page load, functions will work, but if you hover again, nothing will be happened. How can I overcome this problem?

```
  $('#resizable').resizable({
    aspectRatio:false
  });
  $('.ui-resizable-se').hover(function(){
    keep("resizable");
  });
  $('.ui-resizable-e').hover(function(){
    dontKeep("resizable");
  });
```

Source link: http://jsfiddle.net/nNrgP/

Comment: `live` is deprecated as of version 1.7 and was removed in 1.9. You should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The hovers do not work after the first time because you've called `resizable("destroy");` Calling that

> Removes the resizable functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

[Resizable Destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-destroy)

If you want that to still be available, you should either toggle between `resizable("disable")` and `resizable("enable")`, or completely re-init the resizable div. Without more knowledge of your goal (or other code), it's tough to tell what the best option is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just update the `options`:

```
function dontKeep(val){
    $("#"+val).resizable("option", 'aspectRatio', false);
    alert("dont keep");
}
function keep(val){
    $("#"+val).resizable("option", 'aspectRatio', true);
    alert("keep");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using event delegation since you might be dealing with dynamic eleemnts

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.ui-resizable-e', function(){
    dontKeep("resizable");
});

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.ui-resizable-se', function(){
    keep("resizable");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4s3d9/)